# QUERY simplification with LAMBDA function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this formula so I want to make the same QUERY for each variable and join the results. The given formula works (no error in cell) but it give me only the first query result.

I want the result to be QUERYRESULT1 / QUERYRESULT2 / QUERYRESULT3, etc. and i could repeeat the query for each variable, but I'm asking for a way to make it with only one line (to simplify). Is it possible?

```
=MAP(
  BI3:BI;BL3:BL;BO3:BO;BR3:BR;BU3:BU;BX3:BX;CA3:CA;CD3:CD;CG3:CG;CJ3:CJ;CM3:CM;CP3:CP;
  LAMBDA(f;g;h;i;j;k;l;m;n;o;p;q;
    TEXTJOIN(" / "; TRUE;
      IFNA(
        ARRAYFORMULA(
          IFERROR(QUERY('BDD Componentes'!AR:AV;"SELECT AV WHERE AR = '"&{f;g;h;i;j;k;l;m;n;o;p;q}&"'";0))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: What is your expected result with that QUERY? Return all values in AV that correspond to a match in AR from any of the values from those ranges?

Comment: IFERROR(QUERY('BDD Componentes'!AR:AV;"SELECT AV WHERE AR = '"&f&"'";0))
each query return one string (matched in AR from the lambda argument ranges). And I want all those strings joined with textjoin. I read about using the argument array {f;g;h;i;j;k;l;m;n;o;p;q} in the query all inside an arrayformula, but it's not working because i just receive the first string (corresponding to argument "f")

Comment: But you want a result for each row from the ranges? Or a single cell that joins all matches?

Comment: its a result for each row, that why im using map with column ranges

Answer (score 0):

here I am with the same suggestion as in your previous question. Try it and let me know:

```
=BYROW({BI3:BI\BL3:BL\BO3:BO\BR3:BR\BU3:BU\BX3:BX\CA3:CA\CD3:CD\CG3:CG\CJ3:CJ\CM3:CM\CP3:C};
  LAMBDA(r;
    TEXTJOIN(" / "; TRUE;
      IFNA(
        ARRAYFORMULA(
          IFERROR(QUERY('BDD Componentes'!AR:AV;"SELECT AV WHERE AR = '"&r&"'";0))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Your formula its giving me #REF error (Circular dependency). By the way, I can't use BYROW because the real formula is longer and it has more packages of ranges, it would be like three arrays of ranges { } and byrow only allow one argument

Comment: Can't you stack them? It's not very clear your scenario, please post some representative example, ideally a link and show desired output to help you with it